# Is there an existing interface to access Nuget feed in Azure DevOps project with Service Principal access tokens?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I am trying to fetch Azure Artifacts (through Nuget feed in Azure DevOps) with Service Principal authentication in C# but not able find a good way to do it. Does anyone know if there is an existing support for this?

The closet documentation I found is this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops

In the example code it uses SP token to access DevOps components such as work items and pipelines through SP access token. However, I couldn't find an equivalent component for artifact like Nuget feeds:

```
var vssAadToken = new VssAadToken("Bearer", accessToken.Token);
var vssAadCredentials = new VssAadCredential(vssAadToken);
var orgUrl = new Uri(new Uri(AdoBaseUrl), AdoOrgName);
var connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, vssAadCredentials);
var client = connection.GetClient<**WorkItemTrackingHttpClient**>();
```

Another way I found is by using the Nuget library, but seems it only support username and password authentication, where in my case I want to use access token:

```
var repository = Repository.CreateSource(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3(), "FeedUrl");
repository.PackageSource.Credentials = new        NuGet.Configuration.PackageSourceCredential("FeedUrl", **userName**, **password**, true, "basic");
return await repository.GetResourceAsync<FindPackageByIdResource>();
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to connect to nuget feed in Azure Artifact using a service principal? If so, you can see the detailed info from [Can I use a service principal to connect to feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-use-a-service-principal-to-connect-to-feeds).  If not, could you describe in more detail what you mean by " fetch Azure Artifacts "?

Comment: Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, thanks for your reply! Let me describe the question with more details: one capability we want to develop for our service is to have the service access a Nuget feed in Azure DevOps project (where our customers published their artifacts) and download them for further processing. Previously we were using PAT token to authenticate our service, and we are trying to migrate to use the AAD access token of the First party App representing the service. 
My question is more specific to C# library/SDK supporting this Nuget downloads operations with App access token auth.

Comment: "Previously we were using PAT token to authenticate our service" - Are you able to download artifact when using PAT? Are you using PAT via VssConnection Class? For example, `VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));`?  If so, you just need to change the credential to SP as shown in [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/ServicePrincipalsSamples/ClientLibsNET/0-SimpleConsoleApp-AppRegistration/Program.cs).

Comment: Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, this is exactly where I'm stuck at! In the example it uses WorkItemTrackingHttpClient which is for ADO Work Item operations:
  var client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
Do you know if there is an equivalent one supported for ADO Nuget feed operations?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found such a client to download a NuGet package in Azure artifact. As a workaround, you can call REST API [NuGet - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) and use SP token for authentication.

```
const string organization = "Your org name";
const string project = "Your project name";
const string feedId = "Your feed name";
const string packageName = "Your package name";
const string packageVersion = "Your package version";
const string apiVersion = "7.1-preview.1";
const string url = $"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/nuget/packages/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}/content?api-version={apiVersion}";
const string AadTenantId = "Your Azure AD tenant id";
const string AadClientId = "Client ID for your Service Principal"; 
const string AadClientSecret = "Client Secret for your Service Principal";

TokenCredential credential;
credential = new ClientSecretCredential(AadTenantId, AadClientId, AadClientSecret);
var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default" }), CancellationToken.None);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.Token);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    byte[] byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes($"{packageName}.{packageVersion}.nupkg", byteArray);
    Console.WriteLine("Package downloaded successfully.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to download package: {response.StatusCode}");
}
```

Ensure that you have added your SP into your organization and assign it with **Contributor** role of your target feed.